# What should be in a try block and where to return my values

Tags: php, exception

While learning PHP I've came across this dillema. For example I have this function to check if a client exists in the database.

```
public function is_client( int $client_id ) {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM clients WHERE id='$client_id'";
    $res = DB::run($query)->fetch();
    if(empty($res)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I wanted to add try/catch functionality so I could catch the PDO errors, and this is how it looks after:

```
public function is_client( int $client_id ) {
    try {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM clients WHERE id='$client_id'";
        $res = DB::run($query)->fetch();
        if(empty($res)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
        return $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

But I was wondering, what should I put in the 'try block'? Only the queries? Should I return my values within the 'try block' or outside?

I've tried a little bit more on that so I ended up with the following:

```
public function is_client( int $client_id ) {
    try {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM clients WHERE id='$client_id'";
        $res = DB::run($query)->fetch();
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
        return $e->getMessage();
    }
    if(empty($res)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Can you please explain to me what are the differences between those examples and which is the correct way to do it?

**UPDATE after people answers**

After reading your answers I did this:

```
public function is_client( int $client_id ) {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM clients WHERE id='$client_id'";
    $res = DB::run($query)->fetch();
    if(empty($res)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}// the function returns only boolean now


try {
    if(is_client(11) === true) {
        echo 'client';
    }
    else {
        echo 'client does not exist';
    }
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your first example:

```
public function is_client( int $client_id ) {
    try {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM clients WHERE id='$client_id'";
        $res = DB::run($query)->fetch();
        if(empty($res)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
        return $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Imagine a PDO Exception is somehow thrown during your query (this would happen in the `$res = DB::run($query)->fetch();` line), this would cause execution to jump directly to the `catch`-Block and your `is_client` function (which you'd normally expect to return a boolean) suddenly returns a string.

So, if you're using your `is_client` function like this:

```
if (is_client(123))
{
    echo "We have a valid client";
} else {
    echo "Client Invalid!";
}
```

Would actually print the valid-statement since a non-empty string (your exception error message) evaluates to true.

The correct way would either be to not catch the exception in `is_client` but rather later in your program flow (eg in the block where you're using `is_client`) or to return a valid/expected value (or throw a new/custom exception) in your function, for example:

```
public function is_client( int $client_id ) {
    try {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM clients WHERE id='$client_id'";
        $res = DB::run($query)->fetch();
        if(empty($res)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
        // Somehow write a log file with the error message $e->getMessage()

        return false; // Return false just to be save
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for explanation. "The correct way would either be to not catch the exception in is_client but rather later in your program flow (eg in the block where you're using is_client)" I updated my question, could you please check?

Answer (score 1):

## Try/Catch

### Summary

Put the try/catch block in the code that calls the function, not the function itself.

### Details

The try/catch block will watch for an exception to be thrown and, if an exception *is* thrown, break to the *catch* portion of the block. Specifically in this case that catch block is watching for an instance of `PDOException`.

In the case of an `PDOException` being thrown you'll most certainly not be getting any results back from the query. That being the case it makes more sense to return the exception from the function and skip returning the results that don't exist.

### Recommended Alternative

The normal preferred method for this is to set up the function to throw the `PDOException` back to the code that calls the function and handle the exception in a try/catch block there. This makes sure that your function is consistently returning the same type of value.

Comment: Thank you. I've put the try/catch block outside of the function. Could you please check? I updated my question.

Comment: That's correct! Here's a link to the PHP documentation on [Exceptions](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php). Reading through that will give you a good idea of what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the second example. If `DB::run($query)->fetch()` throws an exception, `if(empty($res)) {` won't be called either way.